# How to Add 'Comments' to a JPEG File Using MFC

Tags: mfc, exif

Within the property window of a JPEG image, there is a tab called 'Summary'. Within this tab, there is a field called 'Comments' I would like to write some MFC code which will add a given string to this field e.g "This is a photo".

Does some kind soul out there know how to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you use libjpeg?  http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net

Comment: I noticed that. But it's too complicated

Answer (score 0):

MFC doesn't provide this functionality, however you can use [GDI+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798.aspx) for the task. The [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462.aspx) class is capable of reading and writing Exif metadata.

This is almost trivial, and explained under [Reading and Writing Metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533832.aspx). However, since the *UserComment* metadata tag allows for different character encodings, things get a little more involved. The following code<sup>1)</sup> implements a command line utility that allows to set (or replace if present) the *UserComment* field:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

int wmain( int argc, const wchar_t* argv[] ) {
    // Input format: AddExifComment "<input filename>" "<comment>" "<output filename>"
    if (argc != 4)
        return -1;

    // Initialize GDI+
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken{ 0 };
    GdiplusStartup( &gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr );
    // Load image
    Image* img = new Image(argv[1]);
    // Construct Unicode comment
    const auto& comment = MakeUnicodeComment(argv[2]);
    // Assign the UserComment property
    PropertyItem propertyItem;
    propertyItem.id = PropertyTagExifUserComment;
    propertyItem.length = comment.size();
    propertyItem.type = PropertyTagTypeUndefined;
    propertyItem.value = (void*)comment.data();
    img->SetPropertyItem(&propertyItem);
    // Save image
    CLSID clsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
    img->Save(argv[3], &clsid);

    // Cleanup
    delete img;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Constructing an appropriately formatted comment takes a bit of work. This is implemented in the following function:

```cpp
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <iterator>
using std::back_inserter;

vector<BYTE> MakeUnicodeComment(const wchar_t* text){
    // Exif 2.2 header for Unicode (UCS-2): 'U', 'N', 'I', 'C', 'O', 'D', 'E', '\0'
    static const char header[]{"UNICODE"};
    static const size_t headerSize{ sizeof(header) / sizeof(header[0]) };

    // UserComment field contains the 8-byte header followed by UTF-16LE encoded code units
    vector<BYTE> buffer;
    std::copy(header, header + headerSize, back_inserter(buffer));
    // Append comment text (NUL terminator is not required)
    auto current = text;
    while (*current) {
        buffer.push_back(*current & 0xFF);
        buffer.push_back((*current >> 8) & 0xFF);
        ++current;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Retrieving the JPEG encoder from its MIME type is copied from [Retrieving the Class Identifier for an Encoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533843.aspx) for reference:

```cpp
int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid) {
    UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0)
        return -1;  // Failure

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
        return -1;  // Failure

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j) {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0) {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;  // Success
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;  // Failure
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Error handling elided for brevity.*

Comment: Many thanks!But my situation is more complex。I want to write EXIF to a image and save the image where it was。I tried your code,but it doesn't work!

Comment: @jsxyhelu: *"It doesn't work"* is not an error description.

Comment: I mean when i open "a.jpeg" and write to "b.jpeg",it works;but when i open "a.jpeg" and write to  "a.jpeg" it does not work.

Comment: @jsxyhelu: So add the meta data to a temporary file (b.jpeg) and rename b.jpeg to a.jpeg when done. If you want to truly do this in-place, you'd have to go with a 3rd party library, or manually implement this using the Windows Imaging Component.

Answer (score 0):

OK,Finally I manage to solove the problem!There is the code:

```html
OK,Finally I manage to solove the problem!There is the code:

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")   
int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT num= 0;
    UINT size= 0;
    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo= NULL;
    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if(size== 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    pImageCodecInfo= (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if(pImageCodecInfo== NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);
    for(UINT j=0; j< num; ++j)
    {
        if(wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format)== 0)
        {
            *pClsid= pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;
        }
    }
    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;
}
// load bitmap from memory,sync way
Bitmap* LoadBitmapFromMemory(const void* memory, DWORD size)
{
    Bitmap* bmp = NULL;
    IStream* stream = NULL;
    if (CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &stream) == S_OK)
    {
        ULARGE_INTEGER uli;
        uli.QuadPart = size;
        stream->SetSize(uli);
        if (stream->Write(memory, size, NULL) == S_OK)
            bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
        stream->Release();
    }
    return bmp;
}
// load bitmap from file,sync way
Bitmap* LoadBitmapFromFile(const TCHAR* file_name)
{
    Bitmap* bmp = NULL;
    HANDLE file_handle = CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (file_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD temp = 0;
        DWORD file_size = GetFileSize(file_handle, &temp);
        if (file_size && !temp)  // the file must be less than 4G
        {
            unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[file_size];
            if (ReadFile(file_handle, buffer, file_size, &temp, NULL))
                bmp = LoadBitmapFromMemory(buffer, temp);
            delete [] buffer;
        }
        CloseHandle(file_handle);
    }
    return bmp;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    Status stat;
    CLSID  clsid;
    char   propertyValue[] = "Fake Photograph";
     Bitmap* bitmap = LoadBitmapFromFile(L"E:/sandbox/stone.jpg");
    PropertyItem* propertyItem = new PropertyItem;
    // Get the CLSID of the JPEG encoder.
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
    propertyItem->id = PropertyTagCopyright;
    propertyItem->length = 16;  // string length including NULL terminator
    propertyItem->type = PropertyTagTypeASCII; 
    propertyItem->value = propertyValue;
    bitmap->SetPropertyItem(propertyItem);
 
    stat = bitmap->Save(L"E:/sandbox/stone.jpg", &clsid, NULL);
    if(stat == Ok)
        printf("FakePhoto2.jpg saved successfully.\n");
    delete propertyItem;
    delete bitmap;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
    return 0;
}
```